# Why is a piece of this mesh stuck in pose mode?

Tags: rigging

When I grab the right foot, I have a glitch. The point where these 3 bones are connected is not moving.

[image: BUG]

Is it a bug? Or can I fix it, somehow?

Comment: weight painting issues, not a bug

Comment: you are right, thx

Comment: @VincentScalia Can you whip up a quick answer.

Comment: Uh, yeah! un momento por favor

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the particular vertex is not assigned to the bone that you are moving. Fix it by going into weight paint mode and painting that vertex red!

Unfortunately, weight painting disagrees with my computer so I can't post an image. :( I will try to have someone put one in for me